# DataWeave text/html output no longer works in Mule 4.2.2+

Tags: dataweave

This code was working until Mule 4.2.2. It reads in HTML formatted text from a file.

`<parse-template doc:name="Parse header.html" target="header"  targetValue="#[output (payload as String) replace /(SUBMIT_PATH)/ with '${help.path}']" 
                location="docroot/header.html"/>`

The error was [image]

The error resolved itself after changing it to:

`output text/plain --- <parse-template doc:name="Parse header.html" target="header"  targetValue="#[output (payload as String) replace /(SUBMIT_PATH)/ with '${help.path}']" 
                location="docroot/header.html"/>`

Did something change in support for text/html?

Answer (score 2):

DataWeave never supported text/html as an output as far as I know. The supported output types are documented in https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-formats. Maybe in previous versions the type was not verified, or the output type inference has changed because of some fix. I would say that is the expected result.